# Intellij executes with wrong java version

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My Project is set to run with Java 11.
[image]

I can build it without any issues, but when I try to run it, it is looking for Java 1.8
[image]

Running on Mac OS 12.2.1
IntelliJ Version 2021.3.2

Comment: Do you have a JAVA_HOME environment variable overriding it perhaps?

Comment: Check your `PATH` environment variable outside of Intellij. Also check `JAVA_HOME`. Align all of that with the JDK you actually want to use. It is generally easier if everything (command line, IDE, ...) points to the same JDK, if applicable.

Comment: Check to make sure your run configuration does not have a different version selected

Comment: That's it the run configuration was the problem. Thanks @Locke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in the run configuration. I needed to specify the java version as well. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 4):

You have to check the following settings match (for Java 17):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also if you use maven check that the correct version is set and if not, change them and reimport the project.

Answer (score 0):

An update for 2023 version of Intelij:

There are 2 different solutions based on the issue at hand:

1. To build maven project, navigate to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner -> and make sure it is the correct java version
2. To run service, change the java version from project structure and run service again